# Order data.frame after numbers within character column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame

```
ID<-c("ID_1","ID_2","ID_3","ID_5","ID_1008","ID_6","ID_10")
SomethingElse<-c(5,6,7,1,2,3,1)
SomeText<-c("Thank","you","for","the","!","help","!")
df<-data.frame(ID,SomethingElse,SomeText)
```

what i need is to order the data.frame according to the ID column but in regard to the Numbers within it (1,2,3,5,1008,6,10), so that the result looks like:

```
    ID  SomethingElse    SomeText
   ID_1             5    Thank
   ID_2             6      you
   ID_3             7      for
   ID_5             1      the
   ID_6             3     help
  ID_10             1        !
ID_1008             2        !
```

My problem is when using the command `df[order(df$ID),]`
it orders the result in lexicographical order
 which is "wrong" and looks like the following:

```
     ID SomethingElse SomeText
    ID_1             5    Thank
   ID_10             1        !
 ID_1008             2        !
    ID_2             6      you
    ID_3             7      for
    ID_5             1      the
    ID_6             3     help
```

Is there any smooth and fast one-liner to solve this issue?

Comment: @user2100721  the `mixedorder` will not work on this.

Comment: @deset It is probably a good idea  to strip off the "ID_" altogether or create a new variable using the inner part of akrun's code.

Comment: @Imo yeah you are right, I thought of that, too, but Im using this IDs all over a much longer code and this is the first step where the order is of importance.
I just shouldn't have used the "ID_" part from the beginning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the non-numeric characters, convert to `numeric` and `order` it

```
df[order(as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", df$ID))),]
#       ID SomethingElse SomeText
#1    ID_1             5    Thank
#2    ID_2             6      you
#3    ID_3             7      for
#4    ID_5             1      the
#6    ID_6             3     help
#7   ID_10             1        !
#5 ID_1008             2        !
```

The `\\D+` matches one more more non-numeric elements in the 'ID' column and we replace it with `''`

```
sub("\\D+", "", df$ID)
#[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "5"    "1008" "6"    "10"
```

Comment: It works just great(!) and thanks to your answer I came up with two different solutions one using strsplit and the other substring. Not as smooth and sophisticated as your answer.
Its just that Im a bit careful with solutions I don't  understand completely (like the regular expression part of the answer). But thats just my personal "quirk". Anyway,Thanks!

Comment: @Deset I added some explanations.  Hope it helps